# How to align text in the first visible line in a Spinner Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner

I do this in a spinner

//the text is aligned to center

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE8aG.png

but i would like to achieve this

//the text is aligned to left

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTjhs.png

how could I do? I tried using the "gravity" but does not work

java code:

```
void addProvinceSpinner() {

    ArrayList<String> listaProvince = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaProvince.add("MILANO");
    listaProvince.add("ROMA");
    listaProvince.add("BARI");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.layout_riga_spinner_inserzionisti,
            R.id.inserzionisti_txt_riga_spinner, listaProvince);

    spinner_province.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

xml code (R.layout.layout_riga_spinner_inserzionisti):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inserzionisti_txt_riga_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#01a0d1"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

main xml code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/inserzionisti_spinner_province"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/inserzionisti_spinner_bg"
    android:prompt="@string/inserzionisti_prompt"/>
```

I just solved...

i had to set

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"

to

> android:layout_width="fill_parent"

in Spinner...

Thanks for all! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create an xml -  raw.xml and put this code:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" // As per your requirement (left, center , right etc)
android:textColor="#454545"
android:padding="5dip"
android:textSize="14dip" />

In class file use like this:

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.im_arrays, R.layout.row_spiner);
```

Comment: doesn't work :( , the result is the same... the text won't align to left :/

Comment: If you want to text align left then nothing to do means don't set anything i tried with above code remove this line only android:gravity="center". It display in left.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this myself today. Indeed not working to set it on the actual text view. You have to change the Spinner's gravity instead (it's enough to do that). Add this:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

To your spinner like this:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/inserzionisti_spinner_province"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/inserzionisti_spinner_bg"
    android:prompt="@string/inserzionisti_prompt"/>
```

I'm using the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`, like this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ...);
```

Comment: There is no property "android:gravity" in spinner

Comment: Yes there is. I double confirmed both with the documentation and in code. For example see the xml attributes section here in the API doc for Spinner: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: To center both the currently selected entry and the dropdown entries, I found it necessary to set android:gravity on both the spinner and the dropdown item layout.